# How to display the song selected album artwork to an ImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently using

```
guard let songs = MPMediaQuery.songs().items else {
        return nil
```

To get a list of songs in the users library, which I then created an if statement to only get the song from the current date, but now I'm trying to get the last song in the loop to have its album artwork displayed on an UIImageView on the storyboard. The loop to get the individual song info is through

`for song in songs`

The code I currently have is

`imageViewOutlet.image = song.artwork?.image(at: CGSize)`
Which returns the error:

Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize.Type' to expected argument type 'CGSize'

I am new to Swift and not sure how to extract the album artwork from the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem/1621743-artwork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGSize is not a valid CGSize value. Pass the value that you want to use (this is the size that system will use when rendering the artwork image), I would recommend passing imageViewOutlet.frame.size